# Garbage Collector javascript method for chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, garbage-collection

Is there any JavaScript method for explicitly cleaning up the browser memory in chrome and Firefox, as doing null is not decreasing the memory back to what it was.

Thanks.

Comment: No there's isn't. Sorry.

Comment: Close the browser/tab. I heard that Chrome discards the memory of the tab when it's closed. otherwise, there is none.